# Where does Mac OS X store the ssh passwords?

Tags: ssh, keychain

Some time ago Sourceforge forced everybody to change the Passwords. A real pain since I use a lot of automated scripts.

One of them uses ssh connection to upload the newest passwords. This one is not asking for the password for every operation. And there are quite a few of them: Start Session, copy files, close session.

Now my guess it that the system is trying to log in with the old password and is not storing the new one after I enter is. Correct me if I am wrong.

Now could anybody tell me where in the key chain Mac OS X is storing the passwords.

And yes, I have a public key set up as well. That is what I used when I was still using Linux. But that does not work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mac OS X doesn't store passwords for the command-line ssh client. It can however remember the password to your private key in the Keychain if you are authenticating via keys.

Comment: I guess that was it. I used keys before but for reason unknown this does not work any more. I even created new keys. I de-installed the MacPorts OpenSSH version. No avail — Now I use `sshpass` from MacPorts. I know a security downgrade what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familear with what Source Forge may be doing... but were you required to generate a key-pair and install them in your source forge account?  Some git repositories work in this manner...

If that is the case you will need to delete the old keypair and generate a new pair...

I don't know if I am going off the deep end here, and will provide instructions if this is the case.

What files are available in ~./ssh  ?

Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

you might try looking at Keychain Access, an application in /Applications/Utilities

Comment: That was where I looked first. But if it is there I did not spot it. I searched for *sourceforge* and all that popped up where the various https:// passwords.